# IBM Websphere - can you extract a Application Properties file?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

When I run the following command:

```
AdminTask.extractConfigProperties('[propertiesFileName /tmp/hrLister.props --configData Applicaition=HRListerEAR]')
```

I get:

```
Configuration data Application=HRListerEAR specified for command extractconfigProperties is invalid
```

However if I use Server=server01 I get ""

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe it is just because you typed it here, but you have a typo in `Applicaition`.  Could that be it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export application properties you have to use `Deployment` instead of `Application` (please dont ask why :-)):

```
AdminTask.extractConfigProperties('[-propertiesFileName /tmp/hrLister.props -configData Deployment=HRListerEAR]')
```